# Tmux does not respond to alt+click as Mac Terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, terminal, tmux

I am very used to using alt+click to move the cursor in Terminal on macOS. I recently switched from screen to tmux and this no longer works despite having mouse-mode set to on in my config (and it is indeed on).

This and the fact that copy paste doesn't work the same way it did in screen is quite frustrating. Any help appreciated.